# Upgrading Drive on Notebook with bitlocker installed?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, bitlocker

Currently have a Windows 7 Ultimate on my Notebook with Bitlocker encrypting the drive. I just have a normal 160GB hard drive now. Just ordered a SSD to replace it. Should i just suspend bitlocker before i upgrade my drive (remember had to do this when i upgraded the bios) or should I totally remove drive encryption before i start?